# "Failure to deallocate CLLocationManager on the same runloop as its creation may result in a crash"

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm seeing this error in the console and not sure what the cause is?   I'm requesting user location once.

`2018-09-12 20:04:26.912292-0400 Watch Extension[40984:3250895] [Client] Failure to deallocate CLLocationManager on the same runloop as its creation may result in a crash`

Code below:

```
import CoreLocation


class WorkoutLocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    private var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    public var formattedWorkoutAddress: String?

    public func getWorkoutLocation() {
        guard CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() else {
            print("User does not have location services enabled")
            return
        }

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters

        let locationAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

        switch locationAuthorizationStatus {
        case .authorizedAlways:
            print("location authorized Always")
            locationManager?.requestLocation()
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("location authorized When in Use")
            locationManager?.requestLocation()
        case .denied:
            print("location authorization denied")
        case .notDetermined:
            print("location authorization not determined")

        case .restricted:
            print("location authorization restricted")

        }

    }


    // MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

                guard let currentLocation = locations.first else { return }

                let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
                geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(currentLocation) { (placemarksArray, error) in

                    if let unwrappedError = error  {
                        print("Geocoder error: \(unwrappedError)")
                    }

                    guard let placemarksArrayUnwrapped = placemarksArray else  { return }

                    if placemarksArrayUnwrapped.count > 0 {

                        if let placemark = placemarksArray?.first {

                            let name = placemark.name ?? ""
                            let subLocality = placemark.subLocality ?? ""
                            let locality = placemark.locality ?? ""
                            let state = placemark.administrativeArea ?? ""

//                            print("address1:", placemark.thoroughfare ?? "")
//                            print("address2:", placemark.subThoroughfare ?? "")
//                            print("city:",     placemark.locality ?? "")
//                            print("state:",    placemark.administrativeArea ?? "")
//                            print("zip code:", placemark.postalCode ?? "")
//                            print("country:",  placemark.country ?? "")

                            let workoutLocationAsString = (name + " " + subLocality + " " + locality + " " + state)
                            print("workoutLocationAsString = \(workoutLocationAsString)")
                            self.formattedWorkoutAddress = workoutLocationAsString

                        } else { print("no placemark")}
                    } else { print("placemark.count = 0")}
                }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("location manager error = \(error)")
    }

}
```

usage:

```
private func handleWorkoutSessionState(didChangeTo toState: HKWorkoutSessionState,
                                           from fromState: HKWorkoutSessionState) {
        switch (fromState, toState) {
        case (.notStarted, .running):
            workoutLocationManager.getWorkoutLocation()
```

Comment: Could you give the error?

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: Probably `handleWorkoutSessionState` is not being called on the main queue, but the deallocation of the object that holds the reference to `workoutLocationManager` is executing on the main queue. Try wrapping `getWorkoutLocation` in a `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Comment: Thanks that was my first thought as well but doesn't prevent the console message.

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to this issue?

Comment: @Performat no I haven't

Comment: How about forcing `CLLocationManager` initialization in a given thread, then force-it to deinit in the same thread it has been created?

Comment: @RodrigoMorbach could you provide some code on how to do this? I'm not exactly sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CLLocationManager` must be created in a run loop. If you don't do that, you will receive the following warning from `CoreLocation`:

> A location manager was created on a dispatch queue executing on a thread other than the main thread.  It is the developer's responsibility to ensure that there is a run loop running on the thread on which the location manager object is allocated.  In particular, creating location managers in arbitrary dispatch queues (not attached to the main queue) is not supported and will result in callbacks not being received.

In your case, it looks like your `locationManager` it's being created in the `main thread`, but an instance of `WorkoutLocationManager` is being used on some other thread, which causes it to be deallocated in this thread, and consequently, deallocating `locationManager` in the very same thread.

One option is to make sure that your instance of `WorkoutLocationManager` will be created and used only in the main thread.

Another option, that I haven't fully tested, is to try forcing the creation and deallocation of `locationManager` in the main thread, like so:

```swift
class WorkoutLocationManager: NSObject {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(initLocationManager), with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
    }

    @objc private func initLocationManager() {
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    @objc private func deinitLocationManager() {
        locationManager = nil
    }

    deinit {
        self.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(deinitLocationManager), with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
    }

}
```

Let me know what you think about it.

Comment: Thank you!  This did get rid of the error in the console...but are there any potential unintended consequences from this?

Comment: Well, I can't really tell. There is a special consideration section regarding `performSelector(onMainThread:with:waitUntilDone:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1414900-performselector#1681244.

Comment: I can't really follow what they're saying Rodrigo.  My flow is I instantiate a custom manager class in InterfaceController1, the manager starts an `HKWorkout` (healthKit app) and sets itself as the `HKWorkoutSessionDelegate`, which then triggers a function (when HKWorkoutState = .running) that calls `self.workoutLocationManager.getWorkoutLocation()` in my code above.  So I don't see anywhere where I'm using GCD or dispatch queues, see any issues?

Comment: @GarySabo, don't see any issues. Try exhausting your unit tests and, maybe, releasing a test version with this implementation and see if any errors or crises arise.