# CLLocationManager suddenly only returning New York, NY on Device?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

This code has always worked reliably but lately (at least on my Watch) it's always returning New York, New York no matter where I am? Did something change in Core Location?

```
import CoreLocation


class WorkoutLocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    
    private var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    public var formattedWorkoutAddress: String?
    
    public func getWorkoutLocation() {
        guard CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() else {
            print("User does not have location services enabled")
            return
        }
        
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        
        let locationAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        
        switch locationAuthorizationStatus {
        case .authorizedAlways:
            print("location authorized Always")
            locationManager?.requestLocation()
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("location authorized When in Use")
            locationManager?.requestLocation()
        case .denied:
            print("location authorization denied")
        case .notDetermined:
            print("location authorization not determined")
            
        case .restricted:
            print("location authorization restricted")
            
        default: () 
        }
        
    }
    
   
    // MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
               
                guard let currentLocation = locations.first else { return }
    
                let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
                geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(currentLocation) { (placemarksArray, error) in
                    
                    if let unwrappedError = error  {
                        print("Geocoder error: \(unwrappedError)")
                    }
                    
                    guard let placemarksArrayUnwrapped = placemarksArray else  { return }
        
                    if placemarksArrayUnwrapped.count > 0 {
        
                        if let placemark = placemarksArray?.first {
                            
                            let locality = placemark.locality ?? ""
                            let state = placemark.administrativeArea ?? ""
                            
                            let workoutLocationAsString = (locality + " " + state)
                            print("workoutLocationAsString = \(workoutLocationAsString)")
                            self.formattedWorkoutAddress = workoutLocationAsString
                            
                        } else { print("no placemark")}
                    } else { print("placemark.count = 0")}
                }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("location manager error = \(error)")
    }
    
    //I added this code below to prevent getting the error "Failure to deallocate CLLocationManager on the same runloop as its creation may result in a crash" code is from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52304969/failure-to-deallocate-cllocationmanager-on-the-same-runloop-as-its-creation-may?noredirect=1#comment95470009_52304969
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(initLocationManager), with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
    }
    
    @objc private func initLocationManager() {
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager?.delegate = self
    }
    
    @objc private func deinitLocationManager() {
        locationManager = nil
    }
    
    deinit {
        self.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(deinitLocationManager), with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you set it in the Scheme?

Comment: Where do you request location permission?  What debugging have you done?  Are you getting the lat/lon for New York or is the problem occurring in the reverse geocode? Are you answered near New York?  Do you have precise location permission?

Comment: @Paulw11 lat/lon are for NY as well, I am in Pittsburgh PA, asking for when in us authorization and `locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters` and have not set it in the Scheme that I can find.

Comment: That's not what I was referring to. In iOS 14+ the user can grant approximate or precise location but even approximate location wouldn't move you from PA to NY. What does the maps app show for your location? Is this on the simulator or a real device?

Comment: @Paulw11 this is on my device and I have precise location switched on.

Comment: What location does maps show?  Is this on your watch?

Comment: @Paulw11 not showing maps, this is just a one time location grab to get the city of a workout (on the watch) - console prints NY/NY here as well, but then I pass on to the iPhone app which also shows NY/NY.

Comment: No, I mean what location do you see if you go into the maps app on your device?  Does the device think it is in New York?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I finally figured it out, I did have a default location of NY/NY set in my Scheme...I must have done it a long time ago and forgot ‍♂️

[image]

Comment: @matt I did and thanks!  I kind of suspected it as well given the clues but when I googled how to do it all i found was for the simulator and only today found out how to edit a scheme for device. 

Comment: @matt I disagree - I Googled about the issue and didn't find Scheme as a possible cause.  I've come across similar posts from others who have done something similarly stupid and helped me solve my issue. Anyone with behavior might save themselves the few hours I lost ‍♂️